# How to declare "anything" using java?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I'm trying to find and read a string from a text file using a ".equal" in java. I know that I can simply do this by using ".contain" instead, but I just want to know if there is anyway to find and read the line like this:

For example I have the following data in the text file:

```
ID1   123   123
ID2   125   136
```

Now

```
String ID="ID1"; 
while ((ss = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null){
if (ss.equals(ID+[anything])){do something} }
```

Why I want to this is to prevent getting result for entering just "ID". So is there any way like a regex or something that can help ?

Clarification :

I want to find the exact match for the ID , for example :

if you enter ID1 then the program says : true 
but false for entering just ID

if I use .contain the program finds the word ID1 or ID2 and because they contain "ID" , then it always returns a true value.

now I want to use .eqaual to find the exact match followed by anything

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't get what your problem is. Can  you clarify your question? Not my down-vote by the way as we haven't given you a chance yet to reply to my request.

Comment: Have you heard of regular expressions? Now is the time to familiarize yourself with them :-)

Comment: for example if something equals anything but through a .eqaul() not any other way ?

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann Clearly yes he has, as he says "So is there any way like a regex or something that can help ?"

Comment: @Klaus yeah I know about regex but just don't know how to use them in here

Comment: @funkybro excellent point ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 1+. You have good answers below, in particular @Klaus. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String ID="ID1"; 
while ((ss = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (ss.matches(ID+".*")){do something} }
}
```

The expresion `.*` means any sequence of characters, even an empty sequence. So if `ID` is "ID1" then it will match any `string` that begins with ID1.

Comment: Thanks tibtof it worked very nice and clean I do have to accept your answer :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
ID.+
```

This will only match if the string has "ID" substring plus one character at least.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression such as:

```
(ID\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

Would let you capture three groups, containing the values of interest. E.g. for this input:

```
ID1   123   123
```

Group one would contain `ID1` group twp would contain `123` and `123`

Comment: He didn't ask for such thing... But nice extrapolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also test the **length** of the line, something like this (less code moved than *regex*) :

```
while ((ss = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null) {
   if (ss.length()>3) {
       // Do your job
   }
}
```